# SQL Server todos los usuarios pueden modificar el usuario SA?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Tengo SQL Server 2008 R2.

Estoy haciendo una API que accede a un servidor sql server externo. Quiero tener un usuario en sqlserver que sólo tenga permisos de lectura en una de las bases.

Siguiendo un instructivo, creé un usuario nuevo, sólo le asigné una base de datos y le dí permisos de lectura únicamente en esa base. hasta ahí funcionó.

Sin embargo, si me logueo con ese usuario en el Management Studio, puedo modificar las propiedades del usuario "sa".

He probado con los "Elementos que pueden protegerse" en las propiedades del usuario (servidores e inicios de sesión), pero nada lo cambia.

Hay alguna forma de hacer esto? Me preocupa que alguien pueda ver la clave del usuario en la API e ingrese al servidor.

Gracias.

Comment: Seguro que solo le pusiste propiedades de lectura, asi como dices no deberia poder modificar usuarios si le diste permiso solo a un DB y permisos de solo lectura, podrias poner de que documento te basaste o una imagen de como quedo el usuario

Comment: Hola Edgar, sí, ví que no puedo modificarlo, pero no hay forma de que no pueda *verlo* ?

Comment: Si son otros permisos para no ver los objetos

Comment: Me puedes decir cuales? No los puedo encontrar